# Where should I implement firebase authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

Im watching this tutorial that uses the firebase client library **in cloud functions** to authenticate users. I am starting to doubt wether this is the right approach. Should I do all the authentication in the react app instead? The tutorial explains that the benefit of doing everything server side is that it decreases the amount of things the user has to download to run the application.

That being said, Im having difficulty getting the client library to work with typescript which makes me just want to scrap it. How should I proceed?

Comment: I'm confused about how the client-side library could work "in cloud functions." Can you clarify?

Comment: Heres a time coded link: https://youtu.be/m_u6P5k0vP0?t=2588

Answer (score 2):

It is generally better practice to host authentication (and especially authentication logic) in the back-end, if not for performance, definitely for security reasons.

That said, you can avoid using cloud functions for this authentication with firebase! Here is an alternative super simple video tutorial you may like instead from Fireship: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQyrwxMPm88. The [Google Firebase YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/firebase/videos) also has many videos on the subject.

Cloud functions are useful for when you want parallel action to be taken in the **back-end** during or after login, while the [useAuthState()](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/auth/README.md#useauthstate) react hook is great for when you want parallel action to be taken in the **front-end** during or after login.

Answer (score 2):

so my view on the best approach to solve this on Firebase is to either:

A) Use the Auth Firebase SDK for your client to create users and sign in users,
B) Do it with the Auth REST API

The end result is the same, you get your users into Firebase and you can sign them in and get their auth tokens. The SDK runs on the client, the REST API runs on the server. Once that's done, you can use the user token and pass it to cloud functions to do whatever you need and check the token validity and permissions server side.

On the cloud functions you're supposed to use the Admin SDK, not the client SDK. And the admin SDK has all privileges. For a more specific reason why you SHOULD NOT use the client SDK on cloud functions, is because it keeps state. So 2 users calling your cloud functions, using the client sdk server side, would result in the same user token, which is an error.

I hope I've solved your problem?

Comment: Im looking through the tutorial more, and the guy seems to use the client library only to create accounts. *To be clear, i decided against this and use admin library to create accounts.* For authentication, he switches back to the admin library. Heres how he does it: https://youtu.be/m_u6P5k0vP0?t=5299. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: So, its perfectly fine to use the client SDK to create accounts, and there are some functions it has for that, that are easier to use than the admin SDK. What is a problem is using the client SDK on the server, as in, inside cloud functions. The client SDK should always run client side.

Comment: If you do a cloud func to manage users using the admin SDK, that's going to to work as well, it's just more work. The best solution is to use the client SDK to create/login a user, then client side get that user token, and pass that token to the cloud functions for validation and permissions. Instead of using the client SDK you can also use the REST API version of Auth